# .Obj в массив полигонов С++ без Open GL

Tags: c++

я пишу свой 3d движок на С++. Столкнулся с необходимостью загружать обьекты в проект, выбрал формат obj.Но в интернете я не нашел парсинга его в массив полигонов(Без Open GL).Поэтому задаю вопрос есть ли какие-то либы или функции для загрузки файла Obj?

Comment: https://github.com/thisistherk/fast_obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть большая-большая библиотека [Assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp), и [здесь](https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Assimp) есть описание. Да, это сайт о OpenGl, но загрузка модели никак не завязана на сам OpenGl.

Я в своем маленьком проекте использовал описание, которое нашел [здесь](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/) и используя код оттудова, написал свой парсер. Опять же, это сайт о OpenGL, но код там точно не требует ничего OpenGL зависимого.

Ну как не добавить ссылку на полное описание формата http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/ - сам формат текстовый, так что просмотр в блокноте очень помогает.

Замечу, что в большинстве случае на выходе получаются треугольники, хотя сам формат obj допускает и многоугольники.